# How to register a custom type in Hibernate using org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring

I'm migrating from hibernate 3 to hibernate 4,
In hibernate 3 the way I was registering a custom type was:

```
public class AnnotationSessionFactoryBean extends org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean {
private Collection<? extends BasicType> customTypes;

public Collection<? extends BasicType> getCustomTypes() {
    return customTypes;
}

public void setCustomTypes(Collection<? extends BasicType> customTypes) {
    this.customTypes = customTypes;
}

@Override
protected Configuration newConfiguration() throws HibernateException {
    Configuration configuration = super.newConfiguration();
    if (CollectionUtils.hasEntries(customTypes)) {
        for (BasicType customType:customTypes) {
            configuration.registerTypeOverride(customType);
        }
    }
    return configuration;
}}
```

I'm now trying to do the same operation but using hibernate 4, my question is how is the best way to do this? since I dont have access do change configuration when using "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" instead of "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of your entity classes, annotate the class as follows:

```
@TypeDefs({
  @TypeDef(name="type1",typeClass=me.sample.Type1.class),
  @TypeDef(name="type2",typeClass=me.sample.Type2.class)
})
```

Spring 3.1 merged the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean with the LocalSessionFactoryBean, delegating to the Hibernate configuration whether or not to use annotations vs. XML wiring.

Answer (score 4):

In Hibernate 4, you can use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` without having to extend it:

```
sessionFactory.getConfiguration().registerTypeOverride(TypeOverride.INSTANCE);
```

Although, this will go away in Hibernate 5.0:

NOTE : This will be replaced by use of org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder and org.hibernate.metamodel.MetadataSources instead after the 4.0 release at which point this class will become deprecated and scheduled for removal in 5.0. See HHH-6183, HHH-2578 and HHH-6586 for details

Comment: where do I have to add that?